# changing the code svn2git

Tags: git, svn

Both SVN and GIT repository has been setup on the same server. When we tried to run the script we are getting the following error message.

```
[root@abcd ~]# ./svn2git.pl /home/svntree/testrepo /home/repositories/testrepo.git
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
Invalid GIT commit revision:
```

We are using SVN version  1.1.4 and GIT version 1.7.2.2 for testing purpose.

Comment: Why are you passing the second directory? If I look at the code of svn2git (https://github.com/schwern/svn2git/blob/master/svn2git), the example says: pass only the path to the SVN repo...

Comment: in a script intial we need to pass both svn & git repo

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use SubGit for conversion becase it performs more precise conversion preserving ignores and EOLs concepts and supports Git<->SVN synchronization on-the-fly.